# RavenDB.AspNet.Identity Implicity convert UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, ravendb

I'm using this example https://github.com/JudahGabriel/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity to get RavenDb.AspNet.Identity to work. Everything seemed to ok until this last code-snippet was to be pasted in my code:

```
public AccountController()
{
    this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(() => this.RavenSession));
}
```

The error says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager' to 'AuthTest.ApplicationUserManager'"
..So I'm a bit stuck here. Can someone aslo having this issue tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referencing the wrong assembly. Are you sure your project is picking this one `RavenDB.AspNet.Identity`?

Answer (score 0):

UserStore object should be from RavenDB.AspNet.Identity

See code samples in this project: https://github.com/kdcllc/Chavah

```
static UserStore<ApplicationUser> ConfigureUserStore(IContext arg)
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(arg.GetInstance<IAsyncDocumentSession>());
        return store;
    }
```